# cfgfwk-64254 error occurred in security processing phase execution while creating a new domain

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to create a new domain (Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0, Database 12.1.0.2, Jdk 1.8.0_191, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4) but i'm facing the error below:

```
cfgfwk-64254 error occurred in security processing phase execution
Encoutered error, traceback (innermost last):
File "<iostream>", Line 51,in ?
File "~Oracle_Home/wlserver/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib/socket$py.class" , 
line338, in gethostname 
gaierror (20001,'getaddrinfo failed')
```

Have you any idea about the cause of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From Oracle support : 
_In this case, the issue was caused because the etc/hosts file had the correct IP Address but was referencing a different Host Name.
 
This issue can be caused by a variety of different conditions including:

    Unresolvable Host name
    Unresolvable IP address
    Conflict in the IP Address or Host Name on the network
    Proxy configuration
To resolve this issue, make sure both Host Name and IP Address are resolvable on the network the server is being installed on, and that there are no conflicts._

Comment: I added the adress Ip of my machine in the etc/hosts file and it works. Thanks a lot